# Persist custom metadata categories and properties

Tags: autodesk-data-management

Will the data management API be updated to allow saving your own metadata to objects and files?

If I run a batch process on a set of models, I'd rather not have to run it again on un modified objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Forge APIs except the Design Automation one are read-only.

If you wish to save data in any way whatsoever except using design automation (currently to create or modify DWG files), you will have do so in your own repository somewhere.

If you wish to integrate your updates into the original seed CAD model, you can absolutely do so. However, at the current moment, Forge does not help you with this (except design automation for DWG).

How to achieve this yourself using the current state of things is the topic of my talk on connecting desktop and cloud, BIM and Forge:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/10/connecting-desktop-and-cloud-at-rtc-material.html

Comment: I have an idea that requires processing a model and adding data to it. I would like to do that only in the cloud as I'd be pulling the data from various web services. It sounds like this is not possible right now without creating a desktop application to do the edits. Is there a plan to change that so this could be done cloud-only?